# What is the substitute of FREQUENCY in springjoint2d for springjoint (3d)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In spring joint 2d frequency is time at which the spring oscillates while the objects are approaching the separation distance.

So in spring joint 3d I want to use something for same purpose which is to calculate the time it takes an object to complete one rotation/oscillation around the connect body and break its connection mid-way, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Is your question about C# or UnityScript (you've tagged both)? Also: the Visual Studio tag indicates that your question is about using the Visual Studio application itself, not about code you write with it - is that tag relevant here?

Comment: Frequency is the time it take for an object to return to the same point where started. Spring the start can be any place,not just where the the spring is extended to maximum size.You could use for a spring the minimum distance just as well. For 3d you want to pick an X, Y, Z position and then determine when object gets back to same location (or closest point to same location).  You have to make sure you wait until you leave the original location and then return back to original location.  So normally you create a history of distance from location.  Distance will first grow larger than smaller.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: do you mean to count the time when the object disconnects the object？

Comment: Let me tell you what I actually want, I want to determine when my 3d object comes back to the origin of the spring, so i can detach or remove the spring, in order to achieve that what can i do? Think of an example like angry bird, when i pull it backwards and release it i want it to break the spring connection when it reaches the origin of the spring.